# SQL How to JOIN a table with same columns and use a Join Like statament?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94237/1

DDL and DML:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  id int not null,
  code varchar(20),
  weight varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO product (id, code, weight)
VALUES 
(1, '0001101', '1kg'),
(2, '0001400', '10 x 1kg'),
(3, '0001110', '10kg'),
(4, '0002050', '500g'),
(5, '0003050', '500g'),
(6, '0001WIP', '1kg'),
(7, '0003WIP', '1kg');


CREATE TABLE Stock(
  productID int,
  inStock int
);

INSERT INTO Stock
(productID, inStock)
values
(6, 8),
(7, 0);
```

**Current output**

```
SELECT *
  FROM Product p
JOIN
  Stock s ON p.id = s.productID
JOIN
  product p2 ON LEFT(p.code, 4) = LEFT(p2.code, 4) AND p.weight LIKE '%1kg%'


id  code     weight productID   inStock id  code     weight
6   0001WIP  1kg    6           8       1   0001101  1kg
6   0001WIP  1kg    6           8       2   0001400  10 x 1kg
6   0001WIP  1kg    6           8       3   0001110  10kg  -------- This shouldn't be here
7   0001WIP  1kg    7           0       5   0003050  500g  -------- This shouldn't be here
6   0001WIP  1kg    6           8       6   0001WIP  1kg
7   0003WIP  1kg    7           0       7   0003WIP  1kg
```

The record I marked as **---This shouldn't be here** is the my current problem.

I am basically intending to match up the table stock and table by product codes, by using `LEFT()` and also match up if it contains `1kg`.

**Desired output**

```
id  code     weight productID   inStock id  code     weight
6   0001WIP  1kg    6           8       1   0001101  1kg
6   0001WIP  1kg    6           8       2   0001400  10 x 1kg
6   0001WIP  1kg    6           8       6   0001WIP  1kg
7   0003WIP  1kg    7           0       7   0003WIP  1kg
```

**Question**

How do I achieve such double join? Join by 4 characters from the left and if it contains a 1kg in weight?

Comment: try using CHARINDEX instead of like.

Comment: Please look up First Normal Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM Product p
JOIN
  Stock s ON p.id = s.productID
JOIN
  product p2 ON LEFT(p.code, 4) = LEFT(p2.code, 4) AND p.weight LIKE '%1kg%' AND p2.weight LIKE '%1kg%'
```

Answer (score 1):

change to p2 from p.

```
AND p2.weight LIKE '%1kg%'
```

or if you need both sides than;

```
AND p.weight LIKE '%1kg% AND p2.weight LIKE '%1kg%''
```

Answer (score 1):

I just put your code in and this solves your issue

```
SELECT *
FROM #Product p
INNER JOIN #Stock s ON p.id = s.productID
INNER JOIN #product p2 ON LEFT(p.code, 4) = LEFT(p2.code, 4) 
WHERE CHARINDEX('1kg', p2.weight, 1)>0
```

You might have put the like on the wrong join to product :)

Comment: What is the `Charindex` essentially doing along with `>0`? But it works :)

Comment: Also, I will add that I generally prefer CHARINDEX to %LIKE% because it performs a tad bit better. However if  youre using LIKE% then there shouldnt be that much of a difference.

Comment: So CHARINDEX returns the point in which the string is found. So if you have 'BLAH' and your CHARINDEX('ah', ''blah', 1) you would get a 3 which is greater than 0

Comment: Though it is worth point out the real issue was you were using the wrong alas in your check, whether it was LIKE or CHARINDEX. You were using p and not p2.

Comment: ahh, yes - @mehmetx noted that in his answer.